# Git newbie questions

Tags: git

A little confused on some git commands

1. What is the difference between "`git commit`" and "`git commit -a`"?  My thinking is "`git commit`" is committing all tracked files already so why do we need the "`-a`" option?
2. What is the difference in options with a single dash vs double, e.g. "`git commit -a`" vs "`git commit --all`"?  The documentation says they are the same so why not just a single dash like "`git commit -all`"?
3. I saw some example of using '`git commit -am "a msg"`' but couldn't find documentation on this "`-am`" option.  It Looks like a combined "`-a`" and "`-m`" option.  Is it in general that options can be combined like that or that's just a special case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git commit -a` does the add step for you for all the tracked files.  Not using the `-a` will only commit the files that have staged to be committed.  You can see what those files are via `git status`.

As for your other questions, `-a` vs `--all`, this is common with most scripts to have a shorthand for the option or using `--` to spell the whole word.

Yes, the `-am` is a combination of the two options. Again this is common across many unix scripts.

Answer (score 2):

1. The difference is that git will only commit files added with `git add` to the commit. When doing `git commit -a` it is including all files. using `git add` and `git commit` you can commit part of all the modified files.
2. The one is just shorthand for the other `git commit -a` and `git commit --all` is doing the same thing.
3. The using of `git commit -am"msg"` is correctly a combination of `git commit -a` and `git commit -m"msg"`. This is again just for easy commits with different options, such that you don't have to type the whole thing over and over.

you can find more info on git and how to use it here:
[git documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation)

Answer (score 1):

1. `git commit -a` will stage all tracked files, and then commit them. `git commit` will only commit the files that are already staged. (Staging a file means using `git add`). Read [Git Basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) for more details;
2. The single-dash options with short names are mostly for use in an interactive shell, because they are easier to type. The double-dash options, with long names, are mostly for use in scripts, to ease the work for someone that wants to understand what your script does. It is traditional for a Unix command-line program to provide both. As for why the long name option is not `-all`, see point number 3;
3. Yes, single-dash command-line flags can be combined for brevity. Which is why `-all` does not work - it would mean the same thing as typing `-a -l -l`. Again, that is traditional for Unix command-line flags.

Answer (score 1):

1. -a is used to not to have to use `git add` before committing. But works for already tracked files.
2. double dash is more a Linux thing, long options use --, shortcuts -.
3. options can be used like that in Linux programs.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference between "git commit" and "git commit -a"? My thinking is "git commit" is committing all tracked files already so why do we need the "-a" option?

`$ git commit` commits all staged changes. If you just make a change, and then run `$ git commit`, nothing will be committed because your stage area is empty.

To add a changed file to the next commit, you generally use `$ git add <path>`. However, when you have multiple files, this can be annoying.

The `-a` (or `--all`) option tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

> what is the difference in options with a single dash vs double, e.g. "git commit -a" vs "git commit --all"? The doc says they are the same so why not just a single dash like "git commit -all"?

There is no difference. Options are normally in the form of `--all`, but some common options have a corresponding short version beginning with a single dash such as `-a`.

> I saw some example of using 'git commit -am "a msg"' but couldn't find a doc on this "-am" option. It Looks like a combined "-a" and "-m" option. Is it in general that options can be combined like that or that's just a special case?

You can combine short options together when they don't require an option value. `$ git commit -am` is equal to `$ git commit -a -m`.

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

git commit keys -a -m equal -am